# How would I work with this object or array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, object

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(GeoState)#42 (6) {
    ["errors"]=>
    NULL
    ["attributes":"ActiveRecord\Model":private]=>
    array(3) {
      ["state_id"]=>
      int(7)
      ["state"]=>
      string(11) "Connecticut"
      ["state_abbr"]=>
      string(2) "CT"
    }
    ["__dirty":"ActiveRecord\Model":private]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["__readonly":"ActiveRecord\Model":private]=>
    bool(false)
    ["__relationships":"ActiveRecord\Model":private]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["__new_record":"ActiveRecord\Model":private]=>
    bool(false)
  }
}
```

I just want to echo out state_id, state, state_abbr
I have tried various ways of displaying an array or object info and both varieties I get errors so Im confused now.

Using PHP by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All these object members are private, so you cannot access them directly. Instead look for accessor methods.

Probably this:

```
echo $arr[0]->state_id;
```

would work